# SQL: Get nearest N rows with respect to datetime

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider a table that has meetings data, every meeting is tied to a master meeting. 
example:

```
meeting_id | master_meeting_id | start_at              |
1sq        | a                 | 2019-01-03 11:30:00   | 
2cd        | b                 | 2019-01-01 10:30:00   | 
3as        | a                 | 2019-02-03 11:30:00   | 
4cd        | d                 | 2019-02-03 12:30:00   | 
dw5        | a                 | 2019-03-03 11:30:00   | 
6ds        | a                 | 2019-04-03 11:30:00   |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79638a/1

Given meeting_id, how to fetch the closest(by start_at) meetings tied to the same master_meeting_id in a `single` SQL query?

**example:**

*Input:*

meeting_id=3as

N=1

*Output:*

```
meeting_id | master_meeting_id | start_at              |
1sq        | a                 | 2019-01-03 11:30:00   | 
3as        | a                 | 2019-02-03 11:30:00   |  
dw5        | a                 | 2019-03-03 11:30:00   |
```

Note: I use MySQL

What I have tried so far:
using two SQL queries, one to fetch related rows after start_at, one more to fetch rows before start_at using limit

Edit: edited real table values for start_at
Edit 2: added SQL Fiddle

Comment: `<time>` edit the question and add real `DATETIME` values, we are not here to fill in the blanks..

Comment: okay. doing it.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If you want the nearest N before *and* after it's probably easiest just to `UNION` the results of your two queries.

Comment: I have attached SQLFiddle incase if anyone to play around or try :)

Comment: By 'closest' do you mean 'previous' and 'next'? If so then "`using two SQL queries, one to fetch related rows after start_at, one more to fetch rows before start_at using limit`" is exactly how I'd do - albeit with a UNION to tie them both together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired results with a `UNION` of queries to produce the `N+1` meetings on or *before* the specified meeting (so inclusive of the specified meeting) and the `N+1` meetings on or *after* the specified meeting:

```
(SELECT m1.*
FROM meetings m1
JOIN meetings m2 ON m2.master_meeting_id = m1.master_meeting_id
                AND m2.meeting_id = '3as'
                AND m1.start_at <= m2.start_at
ORDER BY m1.start_at DESC
LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT m1.*
FROM meetings m1
JOIN meetings m2 ON m2.master_meeting_id = m1.master_meeting_id
                AND m2.meeting_id = '3as'
                AND m1.start_at >= m2.start_at
ORDER BY m1.start_at ASC
LIMIT 2)
ORDER BY start_at
```

Output:

```
meeting_id  master_meeting_id   start_at
1sq         a                   2019-01-03T11:30:00Z
3as         a                   2019-02-03T11:30:00Z
dw5         a                   2019-03-03T11:30:00Z
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/79638a/13)

Comment: 2 JOINS, 1 UNION. This gives desired output,. But, is there a version that's a little expensive? :D

Comment: This would be as efficient as you can get due to the requirement that we only look at values from the same `master_meeting_id`. If you only want the closest meetings *regardless of whether they are before or after the specified meeting* you can just use @Stalinko answer.

Answer (score 2):

That wasn't clear what you mean with "closest meetings". I'm assuming you need closest meetings to the given meeting ID. This query will return it:

```
SELECT m2.*
FROM meetings m1
JOIN meetings m2 ON m1.master_meeting_id = m2.master_meeting_id
WHERE m1.id = "given meeting ID"
ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m1.start_at) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m2.start_at))
```

Comment: Thanks, Had to do limit n+1. however is there a way to order the result by start_at? :D

Comment: @SahithVibudhi, simply add `, m2.start_at` to the end :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Accepted the answer! 

Comment: You're welcome @SahithVibudhi, but you've accepted the other answer actually :D